# xcode keeps crashing since hitting the Ignore-Button in source control push dialog

Tags: xcode, git, crash

I am having a serious issue with xCode. It keeps crashing since I once hit the Ignore-Button in the source control push dialog.

I reinstalled my git-repository, I reinstalled xCode, I moved the source folder to a different location - nothing works. It keeps crashing as soon as the push dialog box appears from the top.

I don't know what to do - is this a case for Apple technical support? It is the computer I use for work and therefor quite important.

Maybe I have to delete some application data somewhere or I have to remove xCode in a more complete fashion?

I am running 10.7.4 and xCode 4.3.3

Thanks for any kind of help!

EDIT

Here's the crash log:

> Process:         Xcode [201] Path:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode Identifier:
>   com.apple.dt.Xcode Version:         4.3.3 (1178) Build Info:
>   IDEApplication-1178000000000000~3 App Item ID:     497799835 App
>   External ID: 8553856 Code Type:       X86-64 (Native) Parent Process: 
>   launchd [121]
>
> Date/Time:       2012-06-29 12:39:43.891 +0200 OS Version:      Mac OS
>   X 10.7.4 (11E53) Report Version:  9
>
> Interval Since Last Report:          43432 sec Crashes Since Last
>   Report:           2 Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  28655 sec
>   Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   2 Anonymous UUID:
>   5F9F9EEF-1C99-4FEB-AF57-F16B16584555
>
> Crashed Thread:  9  Dispatch queue:
>   IDESourceControlManagerHoldingQueueLock
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
>
> Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 4E3002
>   ASSERTION FAILURE in
>   /SourceCache/DVTFoundation/DVTFoundation-1195/Framework/Classes/Multicore/DVTDispatchLock.m:45
>   Details:  Non-recursive lock used recursively:
>   IDESourceControlManagerHoldingQueueLock Object:    Method:   -performLockedBlock: Thread:   {name = (null), num = 33} Hints:   None Backtrace:   0 
>   0x000000010d902b9f -[IDEAssertionHandler
>   handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:]
>   (in IDEKit)   1  0x000000010cdb55d5 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in
>   DVTFoundation)   2  0x000000010cd3860a -[DVTDispatchLock
>   performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)   3  0x000000010d41d16d
>   -[IDESourceControlManager handleError:forRequest:operation:waitUntilFinished:withCompletionBlock:]
>   (in IDEFoundation)   4  0x000000010d418189 -[IDESourceControlManager
>   performRequest:waitUntilFinished:withCompletionBlock:] (in
>   IDEFoundation)   5  0x000000010cdd6460
>   __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke_0 (in DVTFoundation)   6  0x00007fff85137a86 _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in
>   libdispatch.dylib)   7  0x00007fff851392d6 _dispatch_queue_drain (in
>   libdispatch.dylib)   8  0x00007fff85139132 _dispatch_queue_invoke (in
>   libdispatch.dylib)   9  0x00007fff8513892c _dispatch_worker_thread2
>   (in libdispatch.dylib)  10  0x00007fff854e53da _pthread_wqthread (in
>   libsystem_c.dylib)  11  0x00007fff854e6b85 start_wqthread (in
>   libsystem_c.dylib)   objc[201]: garbage collection is ON abort()
>   called

Comment: Actually it is a VERY long log. I am not sure what information of this long block is necessary to identify the problem.

Comment: Without logs it is difficult to say anything about this?

Comment: Added the beginning of the log. It is almost 80000 characters long so I can't upload it completely here.